# Combining and Converting separate txt files to JSON Format

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

I'm currently using `C#` and I have 4 `text files` I am working with. I have 100 `data fields` and 50 datafiles corresponding to the data fields. I am trying to join the datafields to the data files in `JSON` format.

Example:
//data fields:

```
Name

Age

Haircolor 

//Data files:

Brian|22||



// double || indicates a blank space.
```

David|21|Brown

Kevin||Black

Is there a way to combine the text files to make it JSON format without writing 50,000 lines of code? Any help or advice is much appreciated.

Comment: So, just to understand it correctly, you have few lines with headers on each in the beginning then each line will contain your records?

Comment: I have 2 separate files I would like to combine.

Comment: The first file that has the titles is in format 
NAME
AGE
HAIRCOLOR
And the second in format 
Brian|22||